# Flex equal height columns and bottom alignment

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list, in my site I will have images inside the wrapper, all varying height. I want each flex row to be the height of the tallest image.

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="wrapper">hello</div></li>
    <li class="large"><div class="wrapper">hello</div></li>
    <li><div class="wrapper">hello</div></li>
    ....
</ul>
```

I have achieved this already using:

```
ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

My issue is that I want to align items to the bottom of each flex row, I can do this via:

```
align-items: baseline
```

This issue here then is that all li's are not the same height.

How can I keep all li's the same height, (without specifying height as it will be dynamic) and align the contents to the base, by using flex. I'm aware you can probably pull this off with table cell or absolute positioning.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ctbb0e7/)

```css
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
li{
  background: gold;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  flex-basis: 20%;
}

.wrapper{
  background: blue;
   //what here?
}

.large{
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><div class="wrapper">hello</div></li>
<li class="large"><div class="wrapper">hello</div></li>
<li><div class="wrapper">hello</div></li>
<li><div class="wrapper">hello</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Will `align-items:stretch` or `align-items:flex-end`do the trick? Or you don't want to stretch the images? Since your images are not of same height, do you want them croped/stretched or leave as they are?

Answer (score 1):

Make each `li` a (nested) flex container.

Then align each div (now a flex item) to the bottom of the `ul`.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

li {
  background: gold;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  display: flex;             /* NEW */
  align-items: flex-end;     /* NEW */
}

.wrapper {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;               /* NEW */
}

.large{
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="wrapper">hello</div>
  </li>
  <li class="large">
    <div class="wrapper">hello</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrapper">hello</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrapper">hello</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0ctbb0e7/2/)